# Color difference between UINavigationBar Tint Color and rest of app in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uicolor, bartintcolor

This is my design in Sketch:

[image]

Sketch says that the blue color is 70,164,239.

So I have the following code for my tab:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 164.0/255.0, blue: 239.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

And the following for the view underneath (inside an action):

```
self.two_buttons_view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 164.0/255.0, blue: 239.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

But look what's going on, the Navigation Bar color is always a little lighter than the color of the view. With this light blue there's only a slight difference but if I go with a darker blue it gets much more noticeable. It appears that the navigation bar's colors are never as rich as the rest of pages views are:

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `tintColor` is a *tint* color. It combines with the translucency (is that a word?) of the bar, along with what's behind the bar, to give some other resulting color.

If you want full control over the *actual* color of a navigation bar, set its `translucent` to `false` and then give it a *background image* consisting of a rectangle of the desired color - and *no* tint color.

Comment: Thanks, @matt. UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false was all that was needed in my case, it looks superb now even when just setting the color itself via the tint color

Comment: In Swift 3 this has changed to: UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

Comment: You don't need to give it a background image.  You can just set its backgroundColor.